# How can I use the administration=read permission in a GitHub action?

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I am creating a JavaScript GitHub Action which invokes several endpoints on the GitHub API, including two which require the `administration=read` permission. It seems that the workflow syntax doesn't allow the `administration` permission to be specified under the `permissions` object. Without that, there doesn't seem to be any way to use the auto-generated token to invoke those endpoints; doing so results in HTTP 403 errors.